unable to mount ext hard disc in Ubuntu 24.04
I have been using Ubuntu 22.04.Recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 and start using it. The Toshiba external1 TB hard disc(format ntfs) when connected shows "Error mounting/dev/sdb1 at media/pillai/TOSHIBA EXT:wrong fs type, bad option,bad superblock on/dev/sdb1/missing codepakage or helper program or other error"
Kindly help to solve this problem

Run sudo dmesg -w in a terminal then connect the drive and it might show some more information about the actual error. And/or look at /var/log/syslog at the time of connection. Update your post with any errors/clues/information.

This question is similar to: NTFS filesystem on external drive isn't recognised: "mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Check if 'ntfs-3g' is installed, else install it

Blacklist 'ntfs3' through the blackist.conf file

Reboot


Hope it helps..!!

No it did not help

I have switched back to Ubuntu 22.04,  that works fine with ext HDD.
